# траблы при установке плагина retrolambda

Tags: плагин, gradle

[туториал ретролямбды](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

при вставке в свой градл этого кода

```
   buildscript {
   repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
   classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5' ********************
   }
   }

   // Required because retrolambda is on maven central
   repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //or apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

В строке со ************ получаю

```
Error:(53, 0) Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:classpath' after it has been resolved.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\JulianDC\Desktop\restaurant\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

я вери нью ту градл как говорится, помогите разобраться почему выдает эту ошибку?

полная градла:

```
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eatgid.com.restaurant"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        /*    jackOptions {
                enabled true
            }*/
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'

        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'


    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    // Required because retrolambda is on maven central
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Android Studio у вас есть 2 файла build.gradle :

Первый - это файл для проекта **build.gradle(Project: имя-проекта)**
сюда помещаем строки:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
     mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
     classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
  }
}

// Required because retrolambda is on maven central
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

**Пример:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7'
        classpath "gradle.plugin.me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Второй - это файл для модуля **build.gradle(Module: имя-модуля)**
сюда помещаем строки:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //or apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

и

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

**Пример:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    // data binding
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        // for retrolambda
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // dependencies
    ...
}
```

Comment: жаль в туториале этого нет

Answer (score 0):

Я просто удалил из грэдла уровня модуля строку apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda' и заработало